How to not create wildcard records using External-DNS?
I am now setting up External DNS to automate the DNS records creation on AWS Route53 for EKS Ingresses. I now have a working setup that can create and delete records depends on ingress existence. However, during the creation, it also created wildcard records for me.
For example, in my Ingress rules, there is only one record abc.example.com. I expect only A and TXT record for abc.example.com would be created. However, there are 6 records in total, 3 for abc.example.com and 3 for *.example.com.
Here is my ingress.yaml and the values.yaml of External-DNS deployment,
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: ingress-test
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
    tls:
    - hosts:
      - "*.example.com"
  rules:
  - host: abc.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: abc
            port: 
              number: 80

sources:
  - ingress
policy: sync
registry: txt
txtOwnerId: external-dns
domainFilters:
  - example.com

And the logs during creation,
time="2024-03-28T17:59:36Z" level=info msg="Desired change: CREATE *.example.com A [Id: /hostedzone/123]"
time="2024-03-28T17:59:36Z" level=info msg="Desired change: CREATE *.example.com TXT [Id: /hostedzone/123]"
time="2024-03-28T17:59:36Z" level=info msg="Desired change: CREATE abc.example.com A [Id: /hostedzone/123]"
time="2024-03-28T17:59:36Z" level=info msg="Desired change: CREATE abc.example.com TXT [Id: /hostedzone/123]"
time="2024-03-28T17:59:36Z" level=info msg="Desired change: CREATE cname-*.example.com TXT [Id: /hostedzone/123]"
time="2024-03-28T17:59:123" level=info msg="Desired change: CREATE cname-abc.example.com TXT [Id: /hostedzone/123]"
time="2024-03-28T17:59:37Z" level=info msg="6 record(s) in zone example.com. [Id: /hostedzone/123] were successfully updated"

Did I make any misconfiguration or it is a bug? External-DNS version 0.14.0 and Chart version 1.14.3.

I have found the solution.
The wildcard record will not create anymore once removed the tls section under spec. I was using the Certificate Discovery feature by tls field. Now I use the Discover vis Ingress host rule method.
Reference: https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/guide/ingress/cert_discovery/
This is my updated ingress.yaml,
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: ingress-test
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
  - host: abc.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: abc
            port: 
              number: 80

However, I doubt a wildcard record should be created just because of using Discover vis Ingress tls method, as this is just a way of attaching TLS certificate instead of a route. Not sure if this case has been discussed before.
Created an issue in official repository: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/issues/4348
